# Automatic log rolling in openshift?

Tags: openshift

I just created a free php gear...
Is the instance automatically configured to roll logs and delete old logs (to make sure we dont go over disk quota?)

Can you pls tell me how often logs are rolled and when old ones get deleted?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment (Feb 2014), all OpenShift Apache-based cartridges use [Apache RotateLogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html) program to rotate logs every midnight:

```
/usr/sbin/rotatelogs <gear-dir>/php/logs/access_log-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%Z 86400
```

The log files are not deleted automatically. However, you can delete them manually using `rhc app-tidy <app>` command. *(Read [more about rhc tools](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install).)*

If concerned about logs eating all your gear capacity, you might consider using [monit community cartridge](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-monit) to trigger automatic email notifications when the app hits 80% of gear storage quota, or to tidy your app automatically. If you already created your app, you can add the monit cartridge with the following commands:

```
rhc env set MONIT_ALERT_EMAIL=my@email.com -a YOUR_APP
rhc cartridge-add http://goo.gl/jiIB2C -a YOUR_APP
```

And last but not least, feel free to open a [new bug report](https://www.openshift.com/open-new-bug) or [new feature request](https://www.openshift.com/ideas) for OpenShift.

Answer (score 3):

At this moment (April 2014), Apache RotateLogs does not seem to be used anymore. [This commit](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/commit/1e96b3f86ad7f37409c4459f7c31b58a09415edc) seems to have changed to use [logshifter](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/logshifter), which reportedly seems to default to rotating every 10MB with a max of 10 log files.

So, to answer your question, it seems like things are automatically configured to roll logs and delete old logs to prevent us from going over disk quota.

BTW, the new logshifter setup combines the access_log and error_log into one log file instead of keeping them separate.